# Printing if different variables are True or False Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm having trouble printing a message after checking if variables are true or false. What I want to do is print variables that are true out of a selecton of variables. There must be an easier way of doing it than the below but this is all I can come up with. I need a better solution or a modification on the below to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
if (quirk) and not (minor, creator, nature):
    print (quirk, item)
elif (minor) and not (quirk, creator, nature):
    print (minor, item)
elif (creator) and not (minor, quirk, nature):
    print (creator, item)
elif (nature) and not (minor, quirk, creator):
    print (item, nature)
else:
    print ("Something went wrong! Properties out of range! Nature =",nature,"Quirk =",quirk,"Minor =",minor,"Creator =",creator)
```

In this case, I always get the error and never any of the prints. The error always shows that one of the variables is true.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are checking if a non-empty tuple is falsish - which is never true. Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) instead.

```
if quirk and not any([minor, creator, nature]):
    print (quirk, item)
# and so on
```

`any([minor, creator, nature])` returns `True` if any of the elements in the collection are `True`, `False` otherwise.

Comment: That totally worked! I'll accept the anser when the system will allow me to. Thanks! I think I need to read up on 'any'.

Comment: @Simkill while you're at it, you might also want to read up on [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), which is a closely related function.

Answer (score 5):

```
(minor, creator, nature)
```

is a tuple. And it always evaluates to `True` in a boolean context, irrespective of the values of `minor`, `creator` and `nature`.

This is what the [documentation for Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) has to say:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **bool**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.

Your non-empty sequence falls into the *"All other values"* category and so is regarded as being true.

---

To express your condition using plain Python logic, you need to write:

```
if quirk and not minor and not creator and not nature:
```

As @Volatility points out, the `any()` utility function can be used to simplify your code and make it read more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

`any` feels like overkill here:

```
if quirk and not (minor or creator or nature):
    print (quirk, item)
elif minor and not (quirk or creator or nature):
    print (minor, item)
elif creator and not (minor or quirk or nature):
    print (creator, item)
elif nature and not (minor or quirk or creator):
    print (item, nature)
else:
    print ("Something went wrong! Properties out of range! Nature =",nature,"Quirk =",quirk,"Minor =",minor,"Creator =",creator)
```